# Deploy phase of a stage not firing

Tags: travis-ci

There has to be something I’m missing, but I just can’t see it. I have a staged build. The deploy *stage* is firing as expected, as are all of its *phases*, but not the deploy phase. Any idea why?

```
stages:
  - name: build
  - name: publish
    if: (type == push && branch == rob-release-and-deploy) || tag IS present
  - name: deploy
    if: (type == push && branch == rob-release-and-deploy) || tag IS present
  - name: clean

# ... Other bits until we hit the deploy stage of jobs: include: ...

    - stage: deploy
      name: "Deploy to dev|aut|stg"
      install:
        - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.23.6/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
        - chmod +x ./kubectl
        - mv ./kubectl ${HOME}/.local/bin
      script:
        - echo "Placeholder?"
      before_deploy:
        - aws ecr get-login-password --region "${AWS_REGION}" | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "${AWS_ECR_REGISTRY_URL}/tmp"
      deploy:
        - provider: script
          script: "bash ./bin/deploy dev"
          skip_cleanup: true
          on:
            branch: rob-release-and-deploy
        - provider: script
          script: "bash ./bin/deploy aut"
          skip_cleanup: true
          on:
            condition: tag IS present && (tag =~ /^\d{8}\.rc\d+$/)
```

I’m committing code to the `rob-release-and-deploy` branch (a PR open on that branch). There’s no indication that the `deploy:` phase is being recognized at all. It’s not being skipped with the message I might normally see if I were pushing to a different branch or something…it’s simply not doing anything at all.

Here's the end of the build log:

```
0.00s$ echo "Placeholder?"
189Placeholder?
190The command "echo "Placeholder?"" exited with 0.
191
192travis_run_after_success: command not found
193travis_run_after_failure: command not found
194travis_run_after_script: command not found
195travis_run_finish: command not found
196
197Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In my second deploy provider, I missing `tags: true`...

```
        - provider: script
          script: "bash ./bin/deploy aut"
          skip_cleanup: true
          on:
            tags: true
            condition: tag =~ /^\d{8}\.rc\d+$/
```

I knew it would be something dumb, but I thought I saw an example in the docs that deployed just using `condition:`. Alas. ¯_(ツ)_/¯